# How to load ARWorldMap from different positions?

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, arkit, arworldmap

Here's what I need to achieve: The user must scan and save their rooms with some AR objects. Then, upon relaunch, the application needs to automatically restore the ARSession with the properly recognized ARWorldMap of a specific room from the saved room list.

Problem: To reconcile the saved world map with the current environment, the user has to be in the same place as they were when they saved the world map.

So, how can I achieve my goal from any place in the room?

Thank you!

I tried to implement solution from the official guide from Apple: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arkit_in_ios/data_management/saving_and_loading_world_data, but it has a problem that i described.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.